# FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

could someone help me because I have already registered all the way through the registrar but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Errors

```
Note: /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.5.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.5.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.1.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.crud_firebase"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Version:

firebase_core: ^1.7.0
firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale hu-HU)
• Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 18116933e7 (10 days ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
• Engine revision d3ea636dc5
• Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/nagysebestyen/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
• Chrome (web)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your packages in your pubspec.yaml file. The latest versions as of now are:

- firebase_core: ^1.8.0
- cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
- firebase_auth: ^3.1.4

Comment: Note: /Users/nagysebestyen/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.5.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.